# Ways to Display Full HTML Page Inside Flex 4

Tags: html, iframe, flex4, adobe

Are there any ways to embed a full HTML page or pages inside a Flex 4 application that actually work? Flex iframe is basically dead and it doesn't work (see my other question here), and `<mx:HTML>` is not robust. I know this is an extremely convoluted situation, but it would take too long to explain here why I need to have this accomplished.

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated. I have searched everywhere online, with no real helpful results.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/10/06/displaying-html-formatted-text-in-a-spark-richtext-control-in-flex-4/

Comment: Thanks, but can this be used to import a full HTML project with CSS and JS attached via other files? I don't think it was meant for that.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't support any HTML tags, or HTML5...

Comment: I have developed a full functional multi tab web browser by using the mx:HTML component. It works pretty well. In what extent is not this component robust for you? Which features would you like to have in it?

Comment: @Anton Thanks, but I am not allowed to use any mx components for this project as they are being deprecated for spark. The closest thing I can find in spark is s:RichText.